# SKMaps v3.0 custom audio file at location

Tags: skmaps

I am using SKMaps v3.0 in my android application and drawing route using the below method.

SKRouteManager.getInstance().calculateRouteWithPoints(pointsList, route);

Everything is working fine, including navigation and voice suggestions. Now my task is to play my own audio file when user is reaches a particular lat, lng position. Is there a call back where I can identify user has reached that point and play my audio file there?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no default notification mechanism for "point along the route reached" (unless that point is a via point) but you can implement this functionality using the POI Tracking mechanism: just define which are the points you should be watching out for and start POI Tracking.

You can read more about this [here](http://sdkblog.skobbler.com/detecting-tracking-pois-in-your-way/) and you can see it in action in the [demo project](http://developer.skobbler.com/support#download), the POI Tracking area.